# Ruby Sleep in a Loop in Thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, loops, sleep

I have the exact same problem posted here a year ago:
[Ruby Loop Failing in Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347853/ruby-loop-failing-in-thread)

Here the code (pretty much the same as in the topic above)

```
 class NewObject
    def my_funk
        t = Thread.new {
            until false do
                puts sleep 15 # sleeps way too much
            end
        }
        t.join
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
    s = NewObject.new()
    s.my_funk
end
```

And here is the output:

```
15
42
36
38
33
45
42
33
32
40
```

The code basically prints the actual number of seconds slept.
Does anyone know what's going on here and how to fix it?

I'm running Windows 7 and Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Don't really know what's going on here, but the code works fine using JRuby 1.5.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: It also works in Ruby 1.9 on Win7. Guess I'll have to update my ruby.

Comment: You have puts sleep 15, it should just be sleep 15 without the puts...

Comment: @Nick, `sleep` returns the actual number of seconds slept, so "puts sleep 15" will attempt to sleep for 15 seconds and then show how many seconds were slept.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, sleep is implemented using the native system call and probably interferes with ruby green threads which are managed by the VM. This would also explain why JRuby and 1.9 do not suffer from the same problem....